# Поиск предложения по словам

Tags: php, mysql, поиск

Делаю поиск по форуму.

Уже сделал поиск по точной фразе, вне зависимости от регистра,
но теперь хочу сделать поиск предложения, но не целиком, а, допустим, по словам.

Т.е., если я делаю запрос на поиск «Ромашки спрятались», то такой текст из базы должен выходить: «Распустились ромашки, спрятались за ними».

Как это реализовать. Через массив же?

Comment: А массив то вам чем поможет ? вы это решили делать полностью средствами php, вытягивая все статьи из базы в память и потом в них искать ? Если уж строить велосипеды - то по крайней мере делать индекс по словам в БД и искать прямо в БД без привлечения массивов и php

Answer (score 3):

### Варианты:

#### Используйте готовое решерние

(elastic search, sphinx, lucene ... google it):

#### Писать самому для удовольствия:

В упрошенном виде все поисковики состоят из 2-х частей.

**Парсер/индексатор** - который пройдтся по тексту и составит индекс.

Как вариант берешь предложение разбиваешь на слова. Считаешь сколько каждое слово встрчаеться. Количество будет твой вес. Чем чаще встречается слово тем тем ближе к верху его нужно вернуть.

```
    Саздаёшь таблицы:
        words
            - id
            - word

        search_index
            - word_id 
            - article_id 
            - weight
```

**Поиск по индексу** (search_index)
        Парсишь запрос и ишешь по таблицам сортеруешь учетом веса.

Comment: Если самому то в mysql можно создать таблицу с индексом поиска, с движком myasm который использует полнотекстовый индекс. после чего уже искать по этой таблице и выводить посты соответствующие ей... Но лучше взять sphinx

Comment: При запросах из нескольких слов так же стоит учитывать расстояние между словами в тексте

Comment: @Naumov Собственно это вариант 1

Comment: @Mike это версия 2. :) Дополнительный функционал ...

Comment: @E_p так дело может и дойти до изобретения поискового движка )) офтоп

Comment: @Naumov Согласен поэтому и написал что для удовольствия

Comment: @Naumov `InnoDB` в mysql 5.6 спокойно использует полнотекстовый поиск, не хуже `myisam`